# Which SELinux policies apply to haproxy?

Tags: selinux

I just bumped into another SELinux related problem. It would seem my `haproxy` wasn't allowed to open TCP connections to the backend and I was able to fix it quickly using Google. Now, I would like to know how one would fix this problem if one actually knew how to work with SELinux?

### The Problem

I want to use haproxy to forward my publicly accessible port 5000 to 127.0.0.1:5601. I configured haproxy accordingly, and did `systemctl restart haproxy` and immediately got this beauty in the syslog:

```
May  9 09:38:45 localhost haproxy[2900]: Server kibana/app1 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "General socket error (Permission denied)", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

`permission denied --> SELinux` has become the dominant short circuit evaluation in my Linux problem solving. Hasn't failed me in years!

### The Solution

[The solution to this problem according to our friends over at Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/654684/125845) is

```
semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 5601
```

because

> SELinux only allow[s] the web server to make outbound connections to a limited set of ports

and apparently the `semanage` command adds port 5601 to that list. This works and now my haproxy serves me Kibana. Great!

### What I don't get/know

When I `ps fauxZ` I see the context of haproxy is `system_u:system_r:haproxy_t:s0`. With the available commands on my Linux, how can I find out that haproxy is restricted by the ports associated with `http_port_t`?

Comment: [Related question with correct answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364091/19575)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SELinux has a bit of a reputation for being arcane - and one that I think is well deserved.

The way I understand it, the context of a program that is running defines what the current policy will permit it to access or do. As such, as you've surmised, the haproxy_t type is allowed some permissions based on the http_port_t type.

Now let's try to actually figure out how to find this relationship.

## Get SELinux label

As you know, `ps -eZ` will list the SELinux labels of running processes - in the case of haproxy, that `user:role:type:sensitivity` is `system_u:system_r:haproxy_t:s0`. The important bit is the type, in this case haproxy_t.

## Permissions

Now to find out which permissions this type has, we can use sesearch[1]:

```
sesearch -d -A -s haproxy_t
```

- `-d` shows only direct results - if you omit this, this will also show all objects from `seinfo --type=haproxy_t -x`!
- `-A` searches for allow rules
- `-s haproxy_t` defines the source type as haproxy_t

Now we get quite a lot of results (106 on my CentOS 7 VM), because, as it happens, there are a lot of different, granular permissions defined.
At this point you need to to know something more about what you're searching for - either the class of what the permission applies to, the target type or the permission name itself.

### Search by class

Let's go with class first: so we know that our source type is `haproxy_t`, and we think that our class might be something to do with the internet, so it's a good bet that it might be tcp_socket.

```
sesearch -d -A -s haproxy_t -c tcp_socket
```

This will list all allow rules for the source type haproxy_t that have anything to do with tcp_socket. That's narrowed it down quite a bit, but it's still anyone's guess which one of these could be the ones we're looking for.

### Search by specific permissions

Next, let's try with permissions - we know that we need our haproxy to bind and connect on specific ports, right? so we try the name_bind and the name_connect permissions.

```
sesearch -d -A -s haproxy_t -p "name_bind, name_connect"

Found 4 semantic av rules:
    allow haproxy_t http_cache_port_t : tcp_socket { name_bind name_connect } ;
    allow haproxy_t commplex_main_port_t : tcp_socket { name_bind name_connect } ;
    allow haproxy_t http_port_t : tcp_socket { name_bind name_connect } ;
    allow haproxy_t port_type : tcp_socket name_bind ;
```

This shows only 4 results, only 3 of which could be our culprit! These results are, as far as SELinux is concerned, the only ports any process with the context of haproxy_t is allowed to bind to.

### Search by target type

This one is a bit of a cheat, because in this case we're actually looking for the target type! But, for the sake of completeness - for instance, if we wanted to find out what permissions haproxy_t gets from http_port_t, we can use the following:

```
sesearch -d -A -s haproxy_t -t http_port_t

Found 1 semantic av rules:
    allow haproxy_t http_port_t : tcp_socket { name_bind name_connect } ;
```

and that, of course, gives us only one result, and the permissions that apply.

## Ports

Now that we know the target objects, and that they are definitions of ports, we can find out exactly which ports they encompass. Well, let's find out:

```
semanage port -l | grep -E 'http_cache_port_t|commplex_main_port_t|http_port_t'

commplex_main_port_t        tcp    5000
commplex_main_port_t        udp    5000
http_cache_port_t           tcp    8080, 8118, 8123, 10001-10010
http_cache_port_t           upd    3130
http_port_t                 tcp    80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
pegasus_http_port_t         tcp    5988
```

And so, we see that tcp port 5601 is nowhere on that list. Now, as far as SELinux cares, you can add that port to any of those types with the `semanage port --add --type XXX --proto tcp 5601` command, and it'll work out. But since this is serving http, http_port_t seems the most applicable type.

Hopefully that demystifies it just a little bit.

[1] Available in the setools-console package.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then this also answers [my other question concerning listenting-on vs. connecting to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363879/19575): We use the type `http_port_t` with the permissions `name_bind` and `name_connect` we indeed use this one list for whitelisting everything we can connect to as well as for whitelisting everything we can listen on. Is that correct?

Comment: I have tried to answer your other question as well. As for whitelisting, `http_port_t` is an umbrella type that tells SELinux all ports that have something to do with HTTP. Whichever port you add to `http_port_t` will then add that port to any service that uses the this type to figure out permissions. In the case of haproxy, that indeed means name_bind and name_connect permissions, but for others, it might be different.

Comment: The most SELinux "friendly" solution would be to define a new port type, generate a new policy that allows name_bind and name_connect to haproxy_t on that type and then enforce it. But that's a different beast entirely - probably a question of its own.

Comment: Great explanation. Although I don't have sesearch installed, thumbs up for listing all allowed ports in `http_port_t`. Allowed me to get the stats listener up on one of those ports

Comment: Thanks for that good explanation. For those who step into `ValueError: Port tcp/9000 already defined` when trying to add the port example 9000, you can do `semanage port --modify --type http_port_t --proto tcp 9090`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure which SELinux setting you have to configure, then:

Install the following packages:

```bsh
yum install setroubleshoot-server
```

then run:

```bsh
sealert -l /var/log/auditd..
```

Following the instructions/recommendations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Muhammad! There's a lot to learn about how the site works, but one of those things is collaborative improvement of posts, including formatting commands differently. Nordine and I were trying to improve your post, but I see you rolled back the improvements. Posts always show who authored them as well as who made what changes. Thank you for your contribution here, and please feel free to look around at other Questions, Answers, and Help pages to familiarize yourself with this set of sites. Thank you!